# How to distribute prefabs evenly around a space in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, spawning

Hello I am currently making a 2D topdown game in unity, in which I want to randomly generate trees and rocks throughout my map. Both are prefabs that you can interact with.

This is my current code. I spawn each prefab at a random position, but need to check that it has a distance of at least 10 to the nearest other prefab I spawned (so that the prefabs are evenly distributed):

```
void SpawnNature() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        {
            Pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-70, 70), Random.Range(-70, 70), 0);
            type = Random.Range(1, 3);
            distance = 100;
            GameObject nearestObject = null;
            float shortestDistance = float.MaxValue;
            foreach(GameObject Object in SpawnedObjects)
            {
                float dist = Vector2.Distance(Object.transform.position, Pos);
                if (dist < shortestDistance)
                {
                    shortestDistance = dist;
                    nearestObject = Object;
                }
            }
            distance = Vector2.Distance(nearestObject.transform.position, Pos);
            if (distance >= 10) {
                if (type == 1) {
                    Instantiate(rock, Pos, Quaternion.identity);
                }
                if (type == 2) {
                    Instantiate(tree, Pos, Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, I am getting a NullReferenceException on line 19. I think this is because something isn't working with finding the distance to the nearest prefab.

I would really appreciate any help. I am a novice programmer and really just want a solution to this. I know this is bad and inefficient code so whether you can fix this code, or have an entirely different approach, I would really appreciate your input!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: well firstly, which is line 19..  where do SpawnedObjects come from? surely shortestdistance will be distance, so why recalculate it?

Comment: Have you tried [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) ..?

Answer (score 0):

Consider first that `nearestObject` starts as `null`.

```
8:            GameObject nearestObject = null;
```

If you try accessing its `.transform`, it will throw an error.

```
8:            GameObject nearestObject = null;
//            ...
19:           distance = Vector2.Distance(nearestObject.transform.position, Pos);
//                                                     ^ NullReferenceException
```

From there you can work your way backwards:

- The `foreach` loops through all of `SpawnedObjects`, so if there are none, it will throw.
- In the first loop, `dist` will almost always be lower than `shortestDistance`  (`float.MaxValue`) excluding some very unlikely scenarios.

So based on this, if you are getting an error, `SpawnedObjects` must be empty and you are not entering the `foreach`.

If it is the first object you're spawning, you likely won't have any `SpawnedObjects`, so you either need to spawn one before looping, or you need to find a different approach checking if `nearestObject` is `null` before accessing it. Don't forget to add the newly spawned object to `SpawnedObjects` either.

ps:
If you're learning programming, try also taking time running your code through the debugger, step through so you can understand the logic and what leads to your errors. A better approach would be to not use `GameObject` or `Transform` and instead build an array of `Vector2`s and then when you're done, loop through that array instantiating your objects

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try learning about the Vector2 array idea. Thank you for the detailed solution. I learned a lot!